# Problema com instalação de pré-requisitos offline - Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, instalador

Estou tentando criar um instalador para meu aplicativo Windows Forms C# que deve baixar seus pré-requisitos do mesmo local do aplicativo, ou seja, instalar offline os pré-requisitos.

Além do .Net Framework 4.8 também necessito da Runtime do .Net Desktop 5.0.7(x64).

[image: Print]

Seguindo fóruns e recomendações, consegui incluir o .NetFramework com sucesso ao inserir o instalador .msi nos seguintes locais:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX48\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe"

e

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX48\pt-BR\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-ptb.exe".

Partindo disso fiz a mesma coisa para a Runtime do .Net Desktop 5.0.7(x64) e inseri o instalador .msi no seguinte local:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\net5desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.7-win-x64.exe"

Mesmo com a pasta nesse local, ao tentar compilar o projeto do instalador tenho o seguinte erro:

```
**ERROR: Para habilitar a opção "Baixar pré-requisitos da mesma localização de meu aplicativo" na caixa de diálogo Pré-requisitos, você deve baixar o arquivo "net5desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.7-win-x64.exe" para o item "Runtime do .NET Desktop 5.0.7 (x64)" em seu computador local. Para obter mais informações, consulte http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.**

**ERROR: General failure building bootstrapper**

**ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x80004005**
```

Eu tinha esse erro também para o .NetFramework 4.8 e resolvi inserindo o instalador na pasta do ClickOnceBootstrapper como indicado acima, mas para a Runtime do .Net Desktop não funciona. Estou esquecendo  ou está faltando alguma coisa? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A localização da pasta onde eu tenho que copiar o instalador do .Net Desktop Runtime é diferente da pasta do .NetFramework.

Copiei o instalador para o seguinte local e funcionou corretamente:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages\net5desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.7-win-x64.exe